# Creating a SSH tunnel with bind option and no remote host

Tags: ssh, networking, network-interface, ssh-tunneling, proxy

I create a SOCKS5 proxy via SSH tunnel as

```
ssh -N -D 8081 -B tun1 user@Remote-IP
```

to use `127.0.0.1:8081` proxy (e.g., in FireFox).

However, I do not want to connect to Remote-IP. I just aim to pass the traffic through `tun1` interface device.

Is it possible to create a local proxy via an SSH tunnel to redirect all the traffic of `127.0.0.1:8081` proxy through a specific network interface without connecting to a remote host?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). Your real question is "how can I pass the traffic through `tun1`?", right? Well, maybe this will help: [*How can I open different browsers' windows with different network adapters?*](https://superuser.com/q/1515856/432690)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes, exactly! it is the problem described in the linked question. I read your answer there. In fact, the other answer to that question suggests a solution similar to what I try here.

Comment: Every tunnel has a destination. So what will be your destination in this scenario?

Comment: @BruceMalaudzi this is indeed the tricky part. The ultimate target is the web where Remote-IP is connected to (e.g., when browsing a website). We build the tunnel from localhost to Remote-IP. Here, I wish to create a tunnel between localhost and `tun1` (or probably its IP).

Comment: Burpsuite and Fiddler does exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Googlebot did you figure this out? I'm trying to do something similar: pfsense with 2 WANs, ISP and VPN; I want SOCKS5 traffic to be routed over VPN. Kamil's solution doesn't work.